# Making multiplication table with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3aSPm/1/)

What I'm trying to do is, make a simple multiplication table.

If the values are '2' and '3', then it should display the result like -

```
2
4
6
```

But, instead it shows -

```
6
```

Could anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: result.innerHTML = x * i;

this changes the content instead of appending to it. Try results.innerHTML += x*i +" ";. Here http://jsfiddle.net/3aSPm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
for (i = 0; i <= y; i++ ) {
    result.innerHTML = x * i;
```

you're rewriting the content of `result` in each iteration.

You should change `+` to `+=`

```
for (i = 0; i <= y; i++ ) {
    result.innerHTML += x * i;
```

Or, for better formating (and if you want the results from `x * 1`)

```
for (i = 1; i <= y; i++ ) {
    result.innerHTML += x * i + '<br />;
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. 

Could you tell me how to have more than one variable in innerHTML? It doesn't work if I do 
    x + x*1
    x x*1

Comment: @Namanyang If you add up two numbers, you get a number `1 + 2 = 3`. If you add a number with string, you get a string: `1 + '2' = '12'`. So you can add an empty string in the beginning, e.g `innerHTML = '' + (x * 1) + (x * 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the `.innerHTML` property on every iteration. Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/3aSPm/5/

```
    var html = "";
    for (i = 0; i <= y; i++) {
        html += (x * i) + "<br>";
        console.log(x * i);
    };
    result.innerHTML = html;
```

I am resorting to the use of a string because of the horrible implications of `+= innerHTML`, mainly that it re-serializes and re-parses everything on each iteration.